# 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB for the right syntax to use near 'str.' at line 1"

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, phpmyadmin

So, I am using Kafka stream and twitter API to get the tweets and to send them to MySQL, but it's not working

```
def insert_tweet(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id):
   query = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id) VALUES ('"+tweet+"','"+username+"',"+str(pnr)+","+str(int(prediction))+","+str(tweet_id)+");"
try:
    conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","","twitter" )
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(query)
    print("Database insertion SUCCESSFUL!!")
    conn.commit()
except MySQLdb.Error as e:
    print(e)
    print("Database insertion unsuccessful!!")
finally:
    conn.close()


def process_data(data):

        print("Processing data ...")        

        if (not data.isEmpty()):
            nbModel=bc_model.value
            hashingTF = HashingTF(100000)
            tf = hashingTF.transform(data.map(lambda x: x[0].encode('utf-8','ignore')))
            tf.cache()
            idf = IDF(minDocFreq=2).fit(tf)
            tfidf = idf.transform(tf)
            tfidf.cache()
            prediction=nbModel.predict(tfidf)

            temp = []
            i=0
            for p,q,r in data.collect():
                temp.append([])
                temp[i].append(p.encode('utf-8','ignore'))
                temp[i].append(q)
                temp[i].append(r)
                i+=1
            i=0
            for p in prediction.collect():
                temp[i].append(p)
                i+=1        

            print(temp)
            for i in temp:
                insert_tweet(str(i[0]),str(i[1]),"0",int(i[3]),int(i[2]))
        else:
            print("Empty RDD !!!")        
            pass

twitter=tweets.map(lambda tweet: tweet['data']['id'])
tweet_text = tweets.map(lambda tweet: tweet['data']['text'])

txt = tweets.map(lambda x: (x['data']['text'], x['data']['id'], x['data']['id']))
txt.foreachRDD(process_data)
```

I tried to run the query manually in MySQL and it worked, so I don't understand what's the problem.
I am using XAMPP v 3.3.0
[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1L9K4.png)

Comment: *"I tried to run the query manually in MySQL"* - Run what query, specifically?  The code shown appears to dynamically **buid** a query, but doesn't show us the result of that logic and what actual resulting query was built.  It would appear that query has a syntax error.  When you debug, what is the actual observed runtime query being executed?  Does it match what you expected it to be?

Comment: Why aren't you using query parameters?

Comment: you can see the query in the 2nd line in the code,
INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id) VALUES ('hello','a',0,0,11210);(I just gave the values manually)@David
But while running the code I am getting the error with the tweet data
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Sir, I am travelling from Rewa to Bhopal. From Maihar station a huge chunk of...' at line 1")
Database insertion unsuccessful!!

Comment: you mean like this?
query = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id) VALUES ('%s','%s',%s,%s,%s);" % (tweet,username,str(pnr),str(int(prediction)))@BillKarwin

Comment: `print(query)` so we can see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, if your `tweet` contains a literal `'` character, it will cause problems with the way you format your SQL.

```
query = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id) VALUES ('"+tweet+"'
```

If the value of `tweet` is:

```
He said: 'Sir, I am travelling from Rewa to Bhopal...
```

Then the resulting SQL will look like the following. Notice that the extra `'` character appears to MySQL as the end of the string!

```
INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id) VALUES ('He said: 'Sir, I am travelling from Rewa to Bhopal...
                                                                             ^
```

This confuses the SQL syntax. MySQL doesn't understand why the end of the quoted string is followed by "Sir, I am travelling..."

If you use Python string-formatting, it doesn't help.

```
query = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id) VALUES ('%s','%s',%s,%s,%s);" % (tweet,username,str(pnr),str(int(prediction)))
```

There will still be mismatched `'` characters, and it results in an SQL syntax error when you run the query.

Query parameters are the best fix for this problem. In the Python connector, it also uses the `%s` placeholder, but you don't format the string values into the string. Also, don't put them in quotes in the SQL query.

```
query = "INSERT INTO tweets(tweet,username,pnr,prediction,tweet_id) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.execute(query, (tweet, username, str(pnr), str(int(prediction)), str(tweet_id)))
```

The `%s` placeholders remain in the `query` string, and you pass a second argument to `execute()` — a list of values to use as parameter values. The Python connector will combine these values in a safe way, so if they contain `'` or any other special character, they won't upset the syntax.

This is shown in code examples here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

Also for future reference, remember that a query parameter can be used only for one scalar SQL value (e.g. where you would otherwise use a quoted string literal or a numeric literal). You can't use parameters for SQL identifiers like table names or column names, or SQL keywords or expressions, or lists of values.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, IT WORKS!!!!!!!!!
This error was bugging me since 2 weeks

Comment: I think you will find that once you get into the habit of using query parameters, they help to avoid lots of difficult bugs like this.